# how to use promise returned by external npm module

Tags: typescript, promise

```
import sharp from 'sharp';
import path from 'path';

const sharp1 = async (filename: string) => {
  return 
    sharp(path.join(__dirname, '../images', filename)).toFile(
    path.join(__dirname, '../src/cache', filename))
    
  
};

export default sharp1;
```

here i am using sharp npm module to edit file .i am trying to use the promise retured but value is undefined.is i am not returning promise properly.

```
sharp1(b).then(result => {
   console.log(result);
```

Comment: What? Please explain yourself

Comment: the element create by javascript dynamically is not using the the already defined background color in style tag.is there a way to use background color already defined in style tag for the element dynamically created .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  This website is very useful 
[tabnine][1]

 image.toBuffer(function(err, img) {
            if ( err ) {
              data.code = 'error-processing-image';
              data.reason = err;
              return reject( data );
            }
    
            data.code = 'processed-image';
            data.obj.Body = img;
            if ( typeof img === 'Buffer' ) {
              data.obj.ContentLength = Buffer.byteLength( img );
            }
            return resolve( data );
          });
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you're pretty much there, however you've formatted your CSS to use the [elements id](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_id.asp) and your JavaScript as a class.

You can correct your CSS to be [a class](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_class.asp);

```
.para1{
    background-color:orange;
}
```

Or your JavaScript to [change the id](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_html_id.asp);

```
para.id = "para1";
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use `para.style = "color: red";` to define an inline CSS.

Or you could add your CSS to the `<style>` tag with:

```
document.querySelector('style').innerHTML += `
#para1 {
    padding: 20px;
}`;
```

**Example:**

```js
var para = document.createElement("div");
para.innerHTML = 'Hello';
para.setAttribute("id", "para1");
para.style = "color: red";
var element = document.getElementById("one");
document.querySelector('style').innerHTML += `
#para1 {
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: orange;
}`;
console.log(document.querySelector('style'));
element.appendChild(para);
```

```html
<style>
  body {
    background-color: skyblue;
  }

</style>
<div id="one"></div>
```

Comment: i want to define padding in style tag and use it without dynamically creating it in javascript .is it possible to load style tag after creating node .

Comment: @Devanshu you did it already in your code width `setAttribute`.

Comment: i think css code is running before javascript due to which already defined style cannot be working  so is there a way to reload the style of css after creating the node@Reza Saadati

Comment: @Devanshu just use your CSS (`<style>` or `<link>`) in the header of your page and use your `<script>` tag in your footer. Then your CSS will be loaded before JavaScript and it should work.

Comment: But if css is loading before the javascript it do not find the dynamic element created by javascript as javascript is loading after css and when css file run the dynamic element does  not get the style .Can i run css after javascript so that it can style to dynamically created element also .HOW to ??@Reza Saadati

Comment: @Devanshu JavaScript can read everything in DOM. So it is important that CSS is loaded in DOM before JavaScript.